# Android Hardware Development

Tags: microprocessor, android, development-tools

I want to learn about Android hardware development (not accessories, but this system itself), although I can find some CPU vendors that make Android versions compatible with their CPU, I can't find more information about the architecture of the system as a whole....for example, how do I develop the GPS part? The 3G part? I bet there is some sort of document that states how things should be connected or even the driver development, I just don't know where to find this information.

I would appreciate if someone could show me where to find this kind of information. I am thinking about playing with the i.MX 6 for custom Android device, but I have no clue how to add GPS and 3G support.

Comment: I would start at http://developer.android.com

Comment: Basically, you build an embedded linux system with these capabilities, and you port androud to it.  It won't be cost effective to duplicate a modern smartphone's functionality, but if you want to for fun you can hunt up peripherals and write android level drivers to integrate them with AOSP.

Comment: One approach you can use often for GPS and 3G is just connecting them to a serial port. Then you can use pppd and gpsd and apart from changing a few config files there shouldn't be much else to do.

Comment: Yes, I know I can just hook up a RS-232 GPS receiver and let's say an I2C 3G GSM module and later write an Android driver for both of them....but is this the right way? The best way? The recommended way? I was hopping for some good documentation, specially on the 3G part since a bad decision will lead to loss in internet speed.

Answer (score 1):

About 5 to 10 companies design and sell these Android development board, essentially

1. Android Pad without casing
2. add Arduino/RPi style hardware pins
3. add 'limited' English manual (original Chinese)

GPS and cellular phone modules, with working example code, are optional purchase. Ask for English manual before buying as only export items have invested time to do English manual.

Examples,

[Android dev Board](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTvWTj6NwBg)
[User Manual](http://www.friendlyarm.net/dl.php?file=mini2440_manual.pdf)